# BIND: Migrate zones from named.conf to rndc addzone without downtime?

Tags: bind, dns-zone

There are two ways to ways to tell bind9 which zones to load: list them in `named.conf` (or the files included from it), and manage them with `rndc addzone`, `rndc delzone` etc.

If I want to move from the first option to the second, is there any way to do that without any downtime?

If I remove a zone from `named.conf`, I have to reload the config before I can run `rndc addzone <zone>`; but that way the zone is gone between the reload and the rnd `rndc addzone` command.

(Which wouldn't be too bad for one zone, but I want to migrate several thousand zones).

I use bind9 version 9.11.5, if that matters.

Comment: Shouldn't your secondary nameserver be able to keep up the service for the zone while you swap it on the primary? Thus, no downtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is any tooling provided for this, but my suggestion for an approach would be:

- Decide what is actually acceptable (I'm going to go with what was suggested by "which wouldn't be too bad for one zone", that minimal downtime might be ok rather than a strict "no downtime" requirement)
- Clone the environment so that you can test this particular migration scenario
- Write a script that enumerates the zone names and the bodies of the zone definitions from a config (the two main things that you will want to feed to `rndc addzone`)
- Run it, and make sure it works. I suppose the state you need to be in is: named running, old zone definitions not loaded but available in a file for your script (easy if those are isolated to some specific include file(s))
- Determine if it's quick enough to be acceptable in terms of downtime. If not, consider an approach of doing it "TV chef-style", having the resulting output already prepared and then just doing an "Indiana Jones-style" swap between old files and new files during downtime.